# derivative of composition of vector valued function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider functions $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $g(t)$ being at least $C^2$. Then $\frac{d}{dt}(F(g(t))=DF(g(t))g'(t)$ and $DF(g(t))$ is a matrix. If I differentiate again
$$\frac{d}{dt}(DF(g(t))g'(t))=D(DF(g(t)))(g'(t))^2+D(F(g(t))g''(t)$$
Am I right? How can I treat $D(DF(g(t))$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $DF \colon \def\R{\mathbb R}\R^n \to L(\R^n,\R^n)$ is map that assigns to every $x\in \R^n$ a linear map $DF(x) \colon \R^n \to \R^n$ ($L(\R^n, \R^n)$ denoting the space of these linear maps). The derivative of this function is a map $D^2F \colon \R^n \to L(\R^n, L(\R^n, \R^n))$, that is at every point $x \in \R^n$ a map $D^2F(x) \colon \R^n \to L(\R^n, \R^n)$ that assigns to $h \in \R^n$ a linear map $D^2F(x)h \colon \R^n \to \R^n$. We can treat (and this is usually done), $(h,k) \mapsto \bigl(D^2F(x)h\bigr)h$ as a bilinear map $D^2F(x) \colon \R^n \times \R^n \to \R^n$. So at every $x\in \R^n$ $D^2F(x)$ is a bilinear map from $(\R^n)^2 \to \R^n$. In coordinates, such a bilinear map is represented (if want to think about like this) by something like a 3d-analouge of a matrix, given by the coordinates of $D^2F(x)[e_i, e_j]$ for each choose of $1 \le i,j \le n$.

Now to the above. Differentiating $(F \circ g)' \colon t \mapsto DF\bigl(g(t)\bigr)g'(t)$ again, we get, as you write
\begin{align*}
  (F\circ g)''(t) &= (DF \circ g)'(t)g'(t) + (DF \circ g)(t)g''(t)\\
        &= (D^2F \circ g)(t)[g'(t),g'(t)] + (DF \circ g)(t)g''(t)\\
        &= D^2F\bigl(g(t)\bigr)[g'(t), g'(t)] + DF\bigl(g(t)\bigr)g''(t)
\end{align*}